# Yii CGridView and dropdown filter

Tags: filter, yii

I created dropdown filter, it's display, but don't worked right. As I anderstand trouble in search() method

view:

```
   $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter' => $model,
        'columns'=>array(
            array(
                'name' => 'client_id',
                'filter' => CHtml::listData(Client::model()->findAll(), 'client_id', 'name'),
                'value'=>'$data->client->name'
            ),
            'task'
         )
    ));
```

I have to tables, and they relations are shown down
model:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'client' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Client', 'client_id'),
    );
}

public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with = array('client');
    $criteria->compare('task_id',$this->task_id);
    $criteria->compare('client_id',$this->client_id);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->client->name);
    $criteria->compare('task',$this->task,true);
    $criteria->compare('start_date',$this->start_date,true);
    $criteria->compare('end_date',$this->end_date,true);
    $criteria->compare('complete',$this->complete);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? What is it outputting?

Comment: I think this wiki might be of some help: 
[CGridView: Render customized/complex datacolumns](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/278/cgridview-render-customized-complex-datacolumns/)

Comment: It's output the same result as before filterin's, i think $this->client_id didn't work right in CDbCriteria

Answer (score 1):

I anderstand my mistake, my controller should look like this:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model=new Tasks;
    if(isset($_REQUEST['Tasks']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Tasks'];
    $this->render('index',array(
        'model'=>$model
    ));
}
```

I forgout pass parametrs from controller to model. Thx all!

Answer (score 0):

Check `rules` method. `client_id` should be in `safe` for `search`

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('client_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview), it explains exactly what you need in a detailed way.

Comment: I tried, but also no result. Sorting work fine, but search by value from dropdown list don't work

Comment: as mashingan stated, check that you have a safe rule for client_id so that it can be mass assigned

Comment: array('task_id, client_search, task, start_date, end_date, complete,client_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search')

Comment: can you confirm that you are getting the value on the server side? whats does print_r($_POST) outputs?

Comment: When I use $criteria->compare('client_id',$_REQUEST['Tasks']['client_id']) instead $criteria->compare('client_id',$this->client_id); all works fine.